# Spring Boot: Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've generated a jar using maven and including this manifest file

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.tdkcloud.TdkCloudApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But when I run

```
 java -jar tdk-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I got this error:

```
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal com.tdkcloud.TdkCloudApplication
```

I've unzipped the jar and the class is there !

Here the manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: tdk-web
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: nunito
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.tdk.web
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_77
Implementation-URL: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/tdk-cloud
 /tdk-web/
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Main-Class: com.tdkcloud.TdkCloudApplication
```

Comment: Can you post your MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.**Set your Start-Class** for Spring boot JarLauncher

```
 <properties>
        <start-class>com.tdkcloud.TdkCloudApplication</start-class>
 </properties>
```

2.**Add Spring Boot maven plugin** into your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

3.After the above changes, Your **generated** **MANIFEST.MF** should look like below.

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.tdkcloud.TdkCloudApplication
```

You can find official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-launching).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this problem was to update the maven project.

[image: The solution I found to this problem was to update the maven project.]